# Google AppEngine (Utilize USB?)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, usb

I am wondering if there is a way that I might utilize USB ports using the google app engine.

I have been doing some research and have had no luck in finding anything that will allow me to physically use a device (e.g. enable and write drivers for) something plugged into a usb port (using python)

Comment: also, this would be for pc based browsers I forgot to mention, not for android

Comment: huh?? are you really asking this question?

Comment: You would need some kind of browser hook into the USB port. It really has nothing to do with Google App Engine. What would you like to do with the USB?

Comment: I am looking to develop my own custom hardware that people will be able to control over the internet via a webpage, hence the reason I need to be able to detect an input/output device plugged into the USB port as well as be able to program a driver for it.

I have looked into extending python with C, that was my first goal, but the google app-engine does not allow the extension of python with C, nor anything else that would have to be compiled.

Comment: Do you actually know what GAE is?

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable question, though the wording could be improved. If you have a piece of hardware plugged into some computer, somewhere (imagine a thermostat hooked up to your home computer, or another data-collection device), controlling it from a browser would be useful. App Engine could serve as a bridge for this.

Comment: Daniel Roseman yes I am fully aware of what the GAE is, yet I was not clear on the subject that I was asking about (Using external devices with the USB).  

Clearly, if I did not know what the GAE was, I would not be asking about the GAE, therefore, clearly, I know what the GAE is, just not the full capabilities that it can actually handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could write a native client application that bridges USB device and App Engine. The app would talk to the USB device via whatever driver you chose. It would send messages to App Engine via HTTP, and receive messages via the Channel API (you'd need to host a browser to do this part), or just poll.

Comment: Thank you for going above and beyond to help me think outside of the box before simply stating no because it has not been done more than once.

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer:  No, you cannot use GAE that way.  A webserver needs to be running on the machine that you plug the USB device into.  I suggest reading up on what GAE really is:  http://code.google.com/appengine/

(Even if you got to know the Google infrastructure engineers (run into them in a bar, buy them drinks, give them flattering comments, etc etc), and you managed to convince them to risk their jobs and install your USB device on a server in their datacenter... It still wouldn't work.  GAE is virtualized, so nobody really knows which physical device is running your app and, even then, it changes as web requests come in.)

It sounds like you need to run your own webserver, at least for the portion of the site that directly interfaces with the device.  Try:  http://httpd.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

As you need to do it on client side, it doesn't matter what you're using on server. You should ask about javascript/html, but i'm sure that it's impossible w/o developing your own native browser plugin. Like Flash, Silverlight, etc. See how you can do it for [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)